# The radius of circle inscribed by an ellipse

Tags: conic-sections

I am trying to find the maximum radius of a circle which is inscribed by an ellipse with equation $(x-1)^2 + 9y^2=1$ 
please I need your help!! Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to Stackexchange. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my exercise, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context: What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, etc. Something to both show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: What is the equation of the circle with center (1,0) and rdius $r$ ? Now how can you know the points of intersection between this ellipse and these circles ? By eliminating for rxample $y$ between these equations. The good $r_0$ is when you have 2 roots but any value $r>r_0$ gives 4  roots.

Comment: @user507682  If you are ok, you can set as solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

it should coincide with the minor semiaxis of the ellipse

Comment: What shall I do ? what are the steps to solve this question 
the question is has no more hint rather than the given equation of ellipse. I think the center of the circle should also be (1,0) and how can I find the maximum radius of the circle which is inscribed by the ellipse